# Psexec with curl or wget

Tags: wget, curl, psexec

I recently found out about psexec and was wondering if this program could help me run wget or curl commands on a remote computer.
is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use it to run any program you are able to launch from a commandline. The syntax for the command is on the Microsoft site:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psexec.aspx

They give a number of examples including:

```
psexec \\marklap c:\bin\test.exe
```

If wget/curl is not on the remote PC you can use the -c switch to automatically copy it over.

Perhaps try it out following the examples and then update your question with what barrier you hit.